# Locked SQL Server UDF

Tags: sql-server, functions

When I try to `RENAME/DELETE` a specific UDF I get the following error:

> Lock request time out period exceeded (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   1222)

Note that if I try to `ALTER` it, the query runs indefinitely.

Here's what I did to try solving the problem without success:

1. `DBCC OPENTRAN()` returns "No active open transactions."
2. `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` returns 0.
3. `BlkBy` column returned by `sp_who2` is empty.
4. I restarted Windows server and manually stopped/restarted MSSQLServer service
5. `chkdsk c:` returns:

   ```
   976657407 KB total disk space.
   114105840 KB in 702392 files.
      424472 KB in 122799 indexes.
           0 KB in bad sectors.
     1885591 KB in use by the system.
       65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   860241504 KB available on disk.
   ```

No problem with all other database objects. This is not a new UDF because I created it several months ago and it worked fine up to 1 hour ago.

If I run `SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.f_GV')`, then I cannot find returned ID value (1505492492) anywhere by executing `select * from sys.dm_tran_locks`. Is my database corrupted?

Comment: Did you try to use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks while your rename/delete statement was running?  How about setting up XE trace for lock count?

Comment: Is the UDF being *used* by some SELECT query?  The select query would not have any locks, but would prevent you from getting a lock to rename/drop the UDF--you can't drop the function if it's in use.

Comment: That will make sense what @AMtwo mentioned.  you can find the dependency by: Click Show Dependencies in the Delete Object dialog box to open the function_name Dependencies dialog box. This will show all of the objects that depend on the function and all of the objects on which the function depends.

Comment: I suspect this is not the real reason because I modified that UDF for several months... up to now... my database contains more or less 1000 objects and I'm currently able to modify them as I prefer. Anyway... I have to solve that problem so I'm going to remove all dependencies by creating a f_GV_2. I'll write here any updates

Comment: Miracle! The UDF, after about 10 hours can be updated as usual!! Any explanation?

Comment: I thought you were trying to delete and not update the UDF!!

Comment: Absolutely. I did a ton of attempts. Rename and Delete commands failed returning a timeout error, Update run undefinitely without return errors. I checked the existence of some long blocking task but my SQL Server Agent performs only minor administrative activites. I created a new database and imported all objects because I suspect that old database is corrupted.